# Why does this function rename the LinkedList node passed as argument?

Tags: java, linked-list

This is from the book I'm using to study java.

LinkedListNode , integer -> LinkedListNode

This function simply iterates through the linked list k times and returns the node.
My question is the following: Is there a point in renaming the parameter from "head" to "current"? Can't I just work on head directly?

```
LinkedListNode getKthNode(LinkedListNode head, int k) {
    LinkedListNode current = head;
    while (k > 0 && current != null) {
        current = current.next;
        k--;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Primarily style. Taste demands always treating parameters as if they were `final` even if they aren't marked as such (that would look messy). Of course, the example code has messed that up with the next parameter, `k`. D'oh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, assigning `head` to `current` is only for the purpose of readability.

The method would behave exactly the same if you modify the `head` local variable directly instead of using the `current` local variable.

If, on the other hand, the `head` reference wasn't passed to the method (i.e. it would be obtained from an instance variable), it would be required to assign it to a local variable in order for your method not to change the `head` of the list.

In such case, `LinkedListNode getKthNode(int k)` would be a method of a `LinkedList` class that has a `LinkedListNode head` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,if you don’t want to modify the head inside the method.You can use the same.

It will behave same. Even if you use head directly.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can rewrite it as follows and expect the same results:

```
LinkedListNode getKthNode(LinkedListNode head, int k) {
    while (k > 0 && head != null) {
        head = head.next;
        k--;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Here's an example of some tests I ran:

First started by creating a `LinkedListNode` class:

```
private static class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    private int value;

    public LinkedListNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then I created 3 `LinkedListNode` objects giving them values 100, 200, 300.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListNode first = new LinkedListNode(100);
    LinkedListNode second = new LinkedListNode(200);
    LinkedListNode third = new LinkedListNode(300);
    first.next = second;
    second.next = third;
    third.next = null;


    System.out.println(getKthNode(first, 1).getValue()); // 200
}
```

If you try the same tests using your original function you'd get the same answer. It's written like it is in an attempt to be expressive.